# Focussing in tvOS using UIFocusGuide

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I've been struggling for a bit with the UIFocusGuide.

So, basically I have a puzzle like below and I want the user to be able to focus the puzzle pieces in a certain order (left to right). I'm able to set the first focus to the first piece no problem (with self.setNeedsFocusUpdate() / self.updateFocusIfNeeded() ). It doesn't work that bad, but the thing is that the focus is not in the right order (from top left and then left, left, left).

Sometimes, when I hit left it goes to the piece down; when I hit up it goes to right, etc. When I try to display the focus guide in the debug mode it's a disaster. The problem is that the puzzle pieces are not the same sizes and not always at the same y coordinate.

Is there a way I could define square zones for the puzzle pieces? I spend so much time and I feel I'm missing something.

[image: example]

There is bunch of code but to place the each `puzzlePiece` (a puzzle piece is a view with an image that has `canBecomedFocused` to true). `puzzleFrame` is the Frame of the Puzzle. I feel to to share this code it's NOT OPTIMIZED at all I'm trying to mainly figure this focus thingy.

```
switch (i) {
            case 1:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+6, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+6)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 2:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+214, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+6)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 3:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+407, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+6)
                puzzlePieceFinale.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 4:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+674, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+6)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 5:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+6, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+222)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 6:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+215, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+218)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 7:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+438, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+196)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 8:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+676, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+216)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 9:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+6, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+424)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 10:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleMain.frame.origin.x+216, y: puzzleMain.frame.origin.y+449)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 11:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+408, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+447)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale
            case 12:
                let positionFinale = CGPoint(x: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.x+644, y: puzzleFrame.frame.origin.y+445)
                puzzlePiece.frame.origin = positionFinale

            default:
                print(i)
        }
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're using for this?

Comment: Those different offsets - are they related to trying to get the left upper puzzle piece corner, depending on the hooks and holes? My guess is, that this really confused the focus engine... Are you able to align those numbers to a nice grid, by adding a "border" to each puzzle tile, not only at the sides with the hooks? Ie increase the tile size to have all the room for any potential hook, then have the pieces overlap, in a "see-through" manner.

Comment: Hi @Baa. Yes all offset are differents and yeah you right that must be confusing for the focus engine. They overlaptoo. Yeah I'm going to try to have each piece be the same size and align them in a grid and have them overlap. I'll let you know if that helped ... Thanks